# I need help getting the correct values after running program

Tags: vb.net

In VB.NET, I need to:

- Calculate the Subtotal based on number of tickets sold and ticket price.
- Calculate the Tax based on Subtotal.
- Calculate the Total by adding Tax and Subtotal.
- Add the Total to the Daily Grand Total (running total).
- Calculate the promoter’s profit of 20% of the Daily Grand Total.
- Display the Subtotal, Tax, Total, Daily Grand Total and Profit.

When I run the program and hit submit after putting in the values for Number of Tickets sold and ticket price, Subtotal and Tax come back fine. 
But I always get a value of 0 in Overall Total and Daily Grand Total. Can't seem to figure out why.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    Dim intTicketsSold As Integer
    Dim dblTicketPrice As Double
    Const dblTax As Double = 0.07
    Dim dblOATotal As Double
    Dim dblSubTotal As Double
    Dim cdblDGTotal As Double
    Const cdblPromoProfit As Double = 0.2

    'Create local variables
    intTicketsSold = txtTicketsSold.Text
    dblTicketPrice = txtTicketPrice.Text
    lblTax.Text = dblTax
    lblOATotal.Text = dblOATotal
    lblSubTotal.Text = dblSubTotal
    lblDGTotal.Text = cdblDGTotal
    lblPromoProfit.Text = cdblPromoProfit

    'Calculate Subtotal
    lblSubTotal.Text = intTicketsSold * dblTicketPrice

    'calculate tax to subtotal
    lblTax.Text = 0.07 * (intTicketsSold * dblTicketPrice)

    'Get the overall total
    dblOATotal = dblTax + dblSubTotal

    'Add Total to Daily Grand Total to get Running Total

    cdblDGTotal = cdblDGTotal + dblOATotal

    'Calculate Promoters Profit of Daily Grand Total
    lblPromoProfit.Text = 0.2 * cdblDGTotal
End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You first assign `lblDGTotal.Text = cdblDGTotal`, and then you calculate the `cdblDGTotal`. Same for `lblOATotal` and `lblDGTotal`.

Comment: @GSerg can you elaborate on that. I feel like i did that in my code.

Comment: Yes, you did that in your code. Is it not the problem? That you first output the variable to a textbox, and then calculate it?

Comment: If I don't then i get an error when I hit submit while running the program

Comment: Given the code `TextBox.Text = i : i = 42`, what will be in the textbox?

Comment: It would just say 42 right??

Comment: No, it would just say 0. Why would it be 42 if you assign 42 to `i` after you copied `i` to `TextBox.Text`? If you thought `TextBox.Text = i` meant "connect `i` to `Textbox.Text` an update the `.Text` whenever `i` changes", then no, it does not work that way.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot for the help. I'm going to make some changes and do some more studying. Got a lot to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not wrong, but you've forgotten to replace the content of Overall Total label and Daily Grand Total label after calculating their values, and the result of `intTicketsSold * dblTicketPrice` should be saved in a variable (dblSubtotal) to use it in Overall Total calculation, that way your calculations will be correct.
Change your code like below:

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    Dim intTicketsSold As Integer
    Dim dblTicketPrice As Double
    Const dblTax As Double = 0.07
    Dim dblOATotal As Double
    Dim dblSubTotal As Double
    Dim cdblDGTotal As Double
    Const cdblPromoProfit As Double = 0.2

    'Create local variables
    intTicketsSold = Convert.ToInt32(txtTicketsSold.Text)
    dblTicketPrice = Convert.ToDouble(txtTicketPrice.Text)
    lblTax.Text = dblTax
    lblSubTotal.Text = dblSubTotal

    lblPromoProfit.Text = cdblPromoProfit

    'Calculate Subtotal
    dblSubTotal = intTicketsSold * dblTicketPrice
    lblSubTotal.Text = dblSubTotal

    'calculate tax to subtotal
    lblTax.Text = 0.07 * (intTicketsSold * dblTicketPrice)

    'Get the overall total
    dblOATotal = dblTax + dblSubTotal
    lblOATotal.Text = dblOATotal
    'Add Total to Daily Grand Total to get Running Total

    cdblDGTotal = cdblDGTotal + dblOATotal
    lblDGTotal.Text = cdblDGTotal
    'Calculate Promoters Profit of Daily Grand Total
    lblPromoProfit.Text = 0.2 * cdblDGTotal
End Sub
```

Comment: All though I am no longer getting the value of ), its now just giving me the value of the tax. Which is 0.07.

Comment: Try the updated code. Subtotal was calculated but never been saved in a variable for next usage.